# How would I answer the following question about the rank of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-rank

Let A = \begin{pmatrix}1&-8&a\\ \:\:\:4&8a&-16\\ \:\:\:a&32&16\end{pmatrix}

Then the rank of A is ? for a = ?, ? for a = ?, and ? for all other values of a."

I am struggling to compute the elimination required so that the matrix below turns into row-echelon form. This is mainly because of the variable a.

Any help on how to proceed will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot just take the determinant? lol

Comment: You could skip elimination and go right for the determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\det\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -8 & a \\
4 & 8 \, a & -16 \\
a & 32 & 16
\end{array}\right]
=-8 \, a^{3} + 384 \, a + 1024
=-8 \, {\left(a + 4\right)}^{2} {\left(a - 8\right)}
$$
Thus our matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $a\neq-4$ and $a\neq8$. That is, $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=3$ if and only if $a\neq -4$ and $a\neq 8$.

To compute $\rank(A)$ if $a=-4$, note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -8 & -4 \\
4 & -32 & -16 \\
-4 & 32 & 16
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -8 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Thus $\rank(A)=1$ if $a=-4$.

Can you compute $\rank(A)$ if $a=8$?